# Looking for a recommendation for a ultra compact/compact with zoom

Tags: equipment-recommendation, battery, compact-cameras

***that runs on either AAA or AA batteries!***

I need something for a somewhat longer trip to an area in which electricity is not so readily available. I was looking at Panasonic's FS, FX and TZ series and they fit me fine except they all run on proprietary batteries, while I need something I can stockpile.

So, generally looking for something in that range but that runs on commonly found batteries.

Does such thing exists? Would appreciate your feedback on this one ...

Comment: http://www.dpreview.com/products/search/cameras#criterias=SpecsCoreParams%2CSpecsBatteryNew%2CSpecsZoomTele%2CAnnouncementYear&includeDiscontinued=No&sort=newestFirst&view=list&page=1&paramSpecsCoreParamsBodyType=UltraCompact%2CCompact&paramSpecsBatteryNew=AA%2CAAA&paramSpecsZoomTele=100%2B&paramAnnouncementYearMin=2010

Answer (score 7):

I use the [Canon SX20IS](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_Camera/PowerShot/PowerShot_SX20_IS/) with incredible results (You can take a look at my gallery [here](http://flickr.com/photos/fotoarte)).

The camera uses four AAA batteries, has a 20x zoom, and has just been replaced by the new [Canon SX30IS](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Cameras/Digital_Camera/PowerShot/PowerShot_SX30_IS) which has a 35x optical zoom.

The quality of the photos are high, and there are a lot of options in Manual mode. It also supports external flashes.

Answer (score 5):

That's an easy search on [Neocamera](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?by=feature), there are [26 ultra-zooms that run on AAs](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?aa=1&by=feature&ultrazoom=1). When you said with zoom, I assume you meant an ultra-zoom since all cameras today have optical zoom anyways.

Among the compact models, the [Canon Poweshot SX130](http://www.neocamera.com/camera.php?id=199) is a good entry-level camera and has full manual controls for creative uses.

[Ultra-compacts with AAs](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?aa=1&by=feature&size=ultracompact) are more rare and have limited zoom. Those are all entry-levels and are very limited in terms of functionality.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to suggestions by Itai, There are two new similar cameras available they are **[Canon Powershot SX150 IS](http://www.dpreview.com/reviews/canon-powershot-sx150-is) and Canon Powershot SX160 IS**.
SX150 has 12x zoom, AA battery with all professional modes like Aperture priority, Shutter priority and Full manual modes with manual focus. You can use this not only for this trip but its an all rounder, useful for many situations.
Most of all its available for such an affordable price.
SX160 is an increment of SX150 at a little higher price and its due this month.